# Checking the incoming and outgoing data of a Web Service

Tags: web-services

I have a web service in C# that I have deployed on IIS 6.0. I want to view the data going out and coming to this web service.

I know about MS SOAP toolkit, but it seems to be deprecated by MS. Does anyone know about any other good tool other than MS soap toolkit. I cannot afford to spend money on any tool, so I need FREE tools if any.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to analyze your network traffic.

And you can also use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to send SOAP Commands to your webservice.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear (to me) from your question, whether this is a one time debugging exercise you are after or a logging-style solution for your app.

For the former I use either [TCPTrace](http://irg.cs.ohiou.edu/software/tcptrace/download.html) (free) or [HttpAnalyzer](http://www.ieinspector.com/httpanalyzer/)

Comment: Hi,

It is a one time debugging exercise. I do not require any logging to be done from within the applicaiton.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MS Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) or the [MS Visual Round Trip Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=119F3477-DCED-41E3-A0E7-D8B5CAE893A3&displaylang=en).